# GKE Global external proxy LB backend services quota limit increase

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have a GKE cluster with one node, we have one load balancer and one ingress to configure 45 rules for our hosts, our developments are microservices and microfrontends, so we need more than 50 Global external proxy LB backend services.

[image]

Quota increases was denied several times.

[image]

Some people have told us to create a new project but I think that this is not a good solution, my cluster still has the capacity (RAM and vCPU) to run more than 50 services.

Creating a new cluster or adding more nodes does not increase the quota.

Perhaps we should have more than one load balancer to increase the quota of Global external proxy LB backend services? (The word 'global' tells me no)

We hope to increase the share of Global external proxy LB backend services without creating a new project or creating a new GCP account.

Comment: Did you any reason for the denial from gcp?

Comment: I think that only the confirmation of the "quota increase request" is received by email, when the status is disapproved, the status appears on the web, when it is approved, an email is received informing the approval and an estimated time to see the changes.

When it is disapproved, a feedback/survey email is received to find out if you agree with the decision but I have not had a clear answer, perhaps my request was processed by bots because we do not have paid GCP support

Answer (score 1):

Google follows a strict and automated process for quota increase and only few exceptional or unique cases are validated by humans however they also follow strict rules while processing your request as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#about_increase_requests). If your request does not meet required criteria it will be denied, so go through the reason why your request was denied (as asked by `Bijendra`) and raise a support ticket if you are still facing this issue. Follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) for creating and managing a support ticket.